# What size is capped in mongodb capped collection?

Tags: mongodb, capped-collections

When specifying the 'size' parameter for a capped collection, which of the following sizes from `db.collection.stats()` is capped to that size?
is it `"size"`, `"storageSize"`, `"storageSize"+"totalIndexSize"` or some other option?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation:

> Optional. Specifies a maximum size in bytes for a capped collection.
>   The size field is required for capped collections. If capped is false,
>   you can use this field to preallocate space for an ordinary
>   collection.

So I would assume it is storageSize.

This would also suggest it is limited on storageSize:

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-5615

Where Elliot says:

> Indexes don't count within the capped size. The capped size is for
>   data alone. Indexes do use space, but b-trees have up to 50% extra
>   space because of balancing. The guarantee is that it'll never be more
>   than 50%.